# How can I explain object-oriented programming to someone who's only coded in Fortran 77?

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran90

My mother did her college thesis in Fortran, and now (over a decade later) needs to learn c++ for fluids simulations. She is able to understand all of the procedural programming, but no matter how hard I try to explain objects to her, it doesn't stick. (I do a lot of work with Java, so I know how objects work) I think I might be explaining it in too high-level ways, so it isn't really making sense to someone who's never worked with them at all and grew up in the age of purely functional programming.

Is there any simple way I can explain them to her that will help her understand? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You're likely to get answers at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on programmers.se. (by the way, Fortran is not functional programming, but procedural programming)

Comment: I was looking for a different se but settled on this one. Thanks for the tip. I'll go post it there.

Comment: Fortran90 isn't "old Fortran"; Fortran 77 might count, but Fortran 66 or Fortran IV or Fortran II — they're "old Fortran".  Remember that 'old Fortran' had no structures more complex than 'array' — no records (so you used parallel arrays to simulate arrays of records).  Strict Fortran 77 has no recursion either.

Comment: In my post on programming I've update the title to reflect the correct language, Fortran 77.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell her to think of objects like objects in the real world. For example the whole world can be a mix of object oriented programming(in C++) with some sort of functional programming(probably done in god's language, Lisp).

Take an object, for example the lawn mower, it has a certain attributes, and it can do a certain thing. (object and class)

Then tell her about a better lawn mower which is an extension of the lawn mower you already have. Tell her its better but still builds on the same mechanism(inheritance).

Then tell her about yourself. Tell her you can sometimes become a lawn mowing expert but you're actually a programmer and do it for a living. This is like you acting as two different entities at the same time. This is polymorphism.

By the time she gets this, tell her about how to implement these things in the language she has to learn(C++).

Then tell her, if she has to write a simulation of this world in the computer world, she will have to learn how to do it.

When she knows how to convert her thoughts of real world into program code. she would have learnt how to program in object oriented programming language.

Comment: This perfect. Thank you so much. Sorry for getting the se wrong, but I guess someone had an answer.

Comment: @Zonedabone no problem, I took 1 year to learn OOP(I learnt on my own), But I used the same examples :) and suddenly felt enlightened. LOL

Comment: @H2CO3 can you believe, something I answered in 2012 October got accepted in February 2013? :-)

Comment: @Aniket Something like this happened to me as well :)